# Where do Deadpool 1 and 2 take place?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

Watching the two Deadpool movies, it's never made clear where they take place.  **In which city (real or fictional) are the Deadpool movies set?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Watching the two Deadpool movies, it's never made clear where they take place.

### It's never stated and the city is not named.

The locations we do see are entirely fictional (although filmed in **Vancouver**).

Where streets *are* named they seem to be named after comic book characters, writer, illustrators or producers.

<sup>[**Source**](http://www.dorkly.com/post/78352/deadpool-movie-easter-eggs-you-might-have-missed)</sup>

[image]

> Don't feel bad if you've never heard of Oyakata -- as far as I can tell, Deadpool's sumo wrestler pal only ever appeared in one issue of the comic (and also a guidebook). Maybe the character meant something special to a member of the production team, or perhaps they just wanted to make a really deep cut for diehard fans.

[image]

> At least a couple of these names are easy to match up. Shaham Rd and Silver Ave point to Tamar Shaham and Scott Aaron Silver, two people who worked on visual effects for the movie. It's prooobably safe to assume that Swagger and Grayson refer to other crew members or friends of the production team, but "Tristan Ave" sticks out as the only first name of the bunch. If everyone's okay with it, I'll go ahead and take credit as the Tristan in this easter egg

[image]

> Starting from the left, the Fort McGuiness exit is for sure a call-out to Ed McGuinness, a classic Deadpool illustrator. "Wernick Pkwy" is no doubt a reference to Paul Wernick, one of the screenwriters. The top-right is especially interesting though, since it's unmistakably a tribute to Steve Ditko, a legendary comic book artist known best for co-creating Spider-Man. It's fitting, since Wade Wilson owes a lot of his design to Marvel's resident wall-crawler.

More at the link above.

Comment: Love this answer and the deep cut references.  I would just add that the highway signs for IH-75 and the proposed IH-98 indicate Detroit-area Michigan. far from both the actual Vancouver and the New York location of the X-Men mansion.  Weird...

Answer (score -7):

> it's never made clear where they take place

YES, yes it is. .

New York, New York. X-Mansion is located in Salem, New York. The cab that Deadpool rides is typical New York Crow Victoria taxi.

They visit S.H.I.E.L.D (damn I don't like to write like that) Carrier wreckage which fallen on New York during that first Avengers Movie.

AAAANd in D1 post credit scene they remade Bueller speech (to the point of wearing same robe and against same background) from **Ferris Bueller's Day Off** which take place in Chicago. Deadpool is in Ferris house.

Comment: 1. A S.H.I.E.L.D. carrier does not fall on New York in the first Avengers movie. A few of them fall on Washington, D.C. in Captain America: Winter Soldier. 2. Ferris Beuller's Day off is set in Chicago, not New York.

Comment: This "answer" doesn't at all make it clear. You reference some references and aren't even right about them.

Comment: Ferris Bueller's Day Off is set in [Chicago](https://chicago.curbed.com/maps/ferris-buellers-day-off-map-guide-chicago).